# Can Apiary disallow or reroute POSTs so data isn't created on production?

Tags: post, apiary.io, apiary

I am adding some POST and PUT routes in my docs on Apiary. If the reader tries testing these routes in the example portion of Apiary.io site they may end up creating bad data on our production server since the URI points right to it.

Aside from changing the base route in the docs to run against a development server instead of production, what do you suggest? Can I somehow tag and force all POSTs and PUTs to only use the Mock server or is there some other trick? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apiary has responded that there is no direct way to do this:

Unfortunately there is no good way how to solve this at the moment on Apiary side. You are indeed correct that tagging actions with some sort of safe, idempotent, unsafe and control these from API settings would be the way to go. However, we are currently far from this approach.

The only that can be done is really to not add the HOST in the blueprint or change its url to something "safe". Other possible solutions would include tweaks on your sever – either detecting the client or solve this using authentication. Using the authentication is, in my opinion, the right way to do this since even if we would implement the tagging at Apiary it would prevent user to go to the terminal and cURL the unsafe actions anyway...